# Trouble casting an object which inherits from a generic base

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I am trying to get to grips with more complicated inheritance structures and generics and I am trying to create some architecture for a current project which is following this suit. My problem currently is I am getting this error:

> Type argument 'Foo' does not inherit from or implement the constraint type 'ListBase'

```
  public class ItemBase {}
  public class ListBase<T> where T : ItemBase
  {
    public virtual List<T> ListExample {get; set; }
  }
```

These are my base classes, although they probably aren't named appropriately I have just tried to show a simple example of what I am trying to achieve.

```
  public class FooItem : ItemBase { }
  public class Foo : ListBase<FooItem>
  {
    public override List<FooItem> ListExample { get; set;}
  }
```

So I can then extend the initial base class for the lists and do more with it, but I want a generic way of handling all of these classes.

```
  public class ListHandler<T> where T : ListBase<ItemBase> { }
```

When I try to pass `Foo` as `T` to the `ListHandler` I get the error mentioned, I thought that inevitably because `Foo` is  a `List<ItemBase>` and `FooItem` is of type `ItemBase` I would be able to do this `var handler = new ListHandler<Foo>();`.

Could anybody explain why I can't do this or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `ListBase<ItemBase>` is not the same as a `ListBase<FooItem>`.
In particular, you can add *any* kind of `ItemBase` to a `ListBase<ItemBase>`.

You need to accept two generic parameters:

```
public class ListHandler<TList, TItem> where T : ListBase<TItem> where TItem : ItemBase { }
```

Comment: So even though `FooItem` is an `ItemBase` I can't do this? I could add `ItemBase` to a `List<FooItem>`

Comment: @LukeHennerley: Wrong; you cannot add an `ItemBase` to a `List<FooItem>`.

Comment: Sorry I see what you mean and knew that just forgot - I have been doing so much generic work arounds today that this has thrown me off course but thanks for explaining what I was doing wrong :)

Comment: @LukeHennerley, SLaks You don't need both arguments -- but you do need the `TItem` argument instead of the `TList`. I.e. it should be `ListHandler<T> where T : ItemBase`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply the type parameter of the *item* type, not the list type. To clarify this, try expanding the `ListHandler` class to include an `AddItem` method which adds a `ItemBase` item to a `ListBase` instance:

```
// As is: Won't work, because there is no way to refer to the constructed
// specific type of ItemBase:
public class ListHandler<TList> where TList: ListBase {
    public TList List { get; private set; }
    public ListHandler(TList List) { this.List = List; }
    public void AddItem(T???? item) { List.ListExample.Add(item); }
}

// Corrected: this will work because TItem can be used to constrain
// the constructed ListBase type as well:
public class ListHandler<TItem> where TItem : ItemBase {
    public ListBase<TItem> List { get; private set; }
    public ListHandler(ListBase<TItem> List) { this.List = List; }
    public void AddItem(TItem item) { List.ListExample.Add(item); }
}

// And this will work just fine:
var handler = new ListHandler<FooItem>(new FooList());
```